# Proper syntax when referencing contracts in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, storage

**Questions:**

1. Capitalization

In `bet.sol`, why is it that `Game` is capitalised when passed as a parameter to `getscoredifference()` and a condition to the subsequent `if` statement, but is not capitalised when used to return a value within that same function?

2. `()`

In `getscoredifference()` of `Bet.sol`, why are parentheses placed at the end of `game.team1Score()`?

3. Type conversion

In the `Bet.sol` constructor, why is the address assigned to the `game` state variable converted to type `Game` when `game` is already of type `Game`?

**Game.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Game {
    int public team1Score;
    int public team2Score;

    enum Teams { Team1, Team2 }

    function addScore(Teams teamNumber) external {
        if(teamNumber == Teams.Team1) {
            team1Score++;
        }
        else {
            team2Score++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Bet.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "./Game.sol";

contract Bet {
        Game game;

    constructor(address _address) {
        game = Game(_address);
    }

    function getScoreDifference(Game.Teams _team) public view returns(int) {
        if(_team == Game.Teams.Team1) {
            return game.team1Score() - game.team2Score();
        }
        else if(_team == Game.Teams.Team2) {
            return game.team2Score() - game.team1Score();
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Game.Teams refers to enum Teams from the imported Game.sol, same goes for the if condition, while returned game is the object initiated in constructor using _address
2. It's a function call on the game object created in constructor (returns the public var values)
3. Same thing, lowercase game here is an instance of the uppercase Game contract initiated with _address